# Binding position of element to another element's bounding box

Tags: wpf

I have a shape contained in a canvas, and I wish to attach a label to the bottom of the aforementioned shape bounding box.
At design time this is trivial, but the shape is meant to be draggable at runtime, and the label should move according to it.
I can "manually" modify the label position in the same Shape_Mouse* methods I use to drag the shape, but I think a binding of some sort would be more clean, and probably required if I want to easily add elements and "attach" to the shape at runtime...

**XAML**

```
<Canvas x:Name="canv" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="531"
        Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="947"
        Background="#FFCDF3EB">
    <Ellipse Fill="#FFF3A7A7" Height="113" Canvas.Left="120" Stroke="Black"
             Canvas.Top="173" Width="125"/>
    <Label Content="Label" Height="39" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="286"
           Width="125"/>
</Canvas>
```

So, is there a way to easily bind the position of an element A to the bottom of element B bounding box in WPF?

Comment: Can you post XAML code?

Comment: @RohitVats I'm not sure why it should be useful, but here it is: 
        `<Canvas x:Name="canv" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="531" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="947" Background="#FFCDF3EB">
            <Ellipse Fill="#FFF3A7A7" Height="113" Canvas.Left="120" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="173" Width="125"/>
            <Label Content="Label" Height="39" Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="286" Width="125"/>
        </Canvas>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way for you to do that is for you to put both the `Canvas` and the `Label` into a `UserControl`. Your `UserControl` XAML would look something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Row="0" ... />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Some description" ... />
</Grid>
```

Now, when the user moved the `UserControl`, both the `Canvas` *and* the label will move together and there's no need for any continuous position calculations.

You can find out more by taking a look a the [User Control in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/user-control-in-wpf/) page on the C# Corner website.

Comment: Yes, that could be a way, but then the `MouseDown` event would refer to the whole `UserControl`, thus moving the shape+label on a click anywhere inside the containint `UserControl`, which is something I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Disregard my last comment, you can handle the pointer in the `shape`, and modify the position of the whole `UserControl` from there, so this is indeed the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You can bind `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` of Label with ellipse so that it moves with shape.

Give `x:Name`  to ellipse and bind using ElementName from Label.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFF3A7A7" Height="113" Canvas.Left="120"
         Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="173" Width="125"/>
<Label Content="Label" Height="39"
       Canvas.Left="{Binding (Canvas.Left),ElementName=ellipse}"
       Canvas.Top="286"
       Width="125"/>
```

`Canvas.Top` won't be same as that of ellipse. So, what you can do is have converter where you will pass `Canvas.Top` of ellipse and add some offset to it and bind with `Canvas.Top` of label just like we did for `Canvas.Left`.